# Replace a variable with a list of numbers

Tags: replacement

How can I replace a variable with a list of numbers?

#### Example

Suppose I have the following list of values

```
V = Table[i, {i, 1, 6.8, 0.19}];
```

and I want to replace `v^2` in the expression `PrC = (v^2 + 1)/(v^2 - 5)` with the list of `V` values.

Comment: `PrC = (v^2 + 1)/(v^2 - 5) /. v^2 -> V`

Comment: Your expression `(v^2 + 1)/v^2 - 5)` is missing a left parenthesis. Do you mean  `(v^2 + 1)/(v^2 - 5)`? Also, you ask about replacing a variable, but your in your example you say you want to replace the *expression* `v^2` with the numbers in a list, which is not the same thing. Which do you really mean?

Comment: YES its (v^2 + 1)/(v^2 - 5) what i want to do is squared all the value of v from 1 to 6.8

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want to do in *Mathematica*. This answer will discus just one -- defining `prc` as a function of `v`. 
Function is one of core concepts of *Mathematica*, so this approach has wide application beyond this specific case.

```
v = Table[i, {i, 1, 6.8, 0.19}];
prc[v_] := (v^2 + 1)/(v^2 - 5)
```

Then to get the values of `prc` over `v` just write

```
prc[v]
```

> ```
> {-0.5, -0.674154, -0.938235, -1.36677, -2.15391, -4.01044, -13.2721, 14.9893, 
>  5.44313, 3.55962, 2.75953, 2.31923, 2.04196, 1.85216, 1.71466, 1.61084, 1.52996, 
>  1.46537, 1.41276, 1.36918, 1.33259, 1.30151, 1.27482, 1.25171, 1.23154, 1.21381, 
>  1.19813, 1.18418, 1.17171, 1.16051, 1.15041}
> ```

That this works may surprise you. It works because `prc` is a the composition of purely numeric functions which have the function attribute called `Listable`, so it has the ability to thread over lists like `v`. I suggest you study [`Listable]`(http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) (follow the link) because you will find it very useful to keep it mind.

Sometimes you will not want to take advantage of the `Listable` attribute, but the function `prc` will still be your friend. As an example, suppose you wanted to plot `prc` directly from the values of v. Then you could simply write

```
 ListPlot[Table[{i, prc[i]}, {i, v}]]
```

which gives

[image: plot]

## Update

There is an alternative way of producing the plot, that I think is worth mentioning. This 2nd formulation is more purely functional, a little more concise, and maybe a little more efficient.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{v, prc[v]}]]
```

It produces exactly the same plot as shown above.